# WHY does multiprocessing not work properly in `__main__.py`

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

The following is the first example in "multiprociessing" [page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) of Python doc.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I have a project root with directory:

```
foo
-- __main__.py
-- file.py
```

Copy paste the above example code into each file.

Running `python file.py` or `python -m file` works; prints `[1,4,9]`.

But running `python foo` or `python -m foo` doesn't. And will actually trap you in an "infinite KeyboardInterrupt loop" or something:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
--- Ctrl + C ---
Process SpawnPoolWorker-8:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-7:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-6:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-5:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-4:
<Some multi-line TraceBack>
KeyboardInterrupt
--- Ctrl + C ---
And you are stuck forever with "Process SpawnPoolWorker-N" where N keeps increasing.
```

I just want to know why `__main__.py` is considered a special case.

From the "Using a pool of workers" [section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) there is a note:

> This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.pool.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.

I know that `__file__` doesn't exist in an interactive interpreter:

```
> python
# enters interpreter
> __file__
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

but it exists when running a file with `python path/to/file.py`

So I wondered if `__main__.py` is somehow treated as an interpreter, but obviously it's not and prints the path to the file: `path/to/__main__.py`.

Please tell me what's going on. I mean, if this `multiprocessing` package is treating `__main__.py` differently, it should say somewhere in the documentation. Or if there is a page that explains how `__main__.py` is treated differently which could cause `multiprocessing` package to treat it differently and I missed it.

I've read a doc [page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) on `__main__` but it doesn't point out any edge case of `__main__.py`.

I'm dying to know please help.

Comment: Which operating system? This works on linux by default but fails if I set multiprocessing to "spawn" (which is the default on windows).

Comment: @tdelaney I'm doing this on Windows. Tried using `set_start_method("fork")` but this context is not available in Windows anyways. On top of it, only the `python foo` doesn't work which runs `foo/__main__.py`. But it works properly when you run the file `foo/file.py`. I wonder if running `python foo` on Linux works.

Comment: @tdelaney And even if changing the context would work, it still doesn't answer my question why does python or `multiprocessing` treat `__main__.py` and other files (file.py) different?

Comment: Running `python -m foo` _does_ work on linux. I had to change to "spawn" to get your error. I'm not sure why its happening. If this is a roadblock, you could move your pool and worker to a different module that you import from main. That should work. But this is certainly puzzling to me.

Comment: This is my guess: "spawn" creates the mp spawning process which imports `__main__.py`. Top level scripts are called `"__main__"` and that's why you have the `if __name__ == "__main__":` check to make sure you don't infinitely import. But in this case, you import a module that is not the top level script but since its `__main__.py`, its module name is still `"__main__"` so that `if` doesn't work and you keep running your create pool code. But multiprocessing.py should have figured this stuff out, right?!

Comment: Just noticed the close as dup vote. That seems right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing needs `__file__` in order to work.  Multiprocessing creates a new Python process that reads the contents of `__file__`, and it expects that that file contains what it needs to know in order to execute the command it has been given.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Then why does it work when you run `python foo/file.py` or `python -m foo.file` but doesn't when running `python foo` or `python -m`? Accessing `__file__` error when doing so in an interpreter. All of these had been addressed in my post. I'm interested in why it doesn't work when used in `__main__.py`.

Comment: And you said "multiprocessing needs `__file__` in order to work". I don't see any `__file__` mentioned in the multiprocessing [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). Please provide a reference.

Comment: @user3290525 - I don't think this is it. You could add `print("__file__:", __file__)` to the top of `__main__.py` to see. Doing so on linux with spawn, the `__file__` is there.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  Please be very specific.  What is the exact contents of file.py.  What is the exact contents of __main__.py.  What command are you running and what error are you getting?